# Cannot use Code review feature in TFS 2012 RC

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I'm trying to use the code review feature when I check-in my files but I get the following message at the top of team explorer :

> To request a code review from your peers, enable the new features. 
>   Click here to enable the new features

When I click the link, it gets me to my project profile site, but I don't see any option to activate the code review feature anywhere...

Comment: This feature is only available in Premium and Ultimate, do you have one of those two editions? because if not, this might be the problem.

Comment: I am working with Premium, so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of these two [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/05/31/deep-dive-on-configure-features.aspx) [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/05/31/how-to-configure-features-for-dozens-of-team-projects.aspx) by Ewald Hofman, they cover the process of upgrading your team project or process template to allow new features.

In the event that the automatic upgrade cannot be performed, follow this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms194972.aspx).

Comment: Looks good, I will try to do what is suggested. I will report the outcome when it is done.

Comment: I ran the program in the second post and all the new features are now enabled for my projects. I hope this will be done automatically in the official release. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you upgraded.  If you upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 RC (instead of to TFS 11 Beta), this is now handled auto-magically - Run the [Configure Features Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your project is likely missing the new work item type definition and related artifacts required for the Code Review functionality to work. That same page I sent has links to instructions on how to add that part manually, but the Configure Features Wizard is a lot less painful.

Comment: Hey Ryan! I just upgraded from TFS2010 directly to 2012 RC so the magic did not operate.
I suggest you take the time to come back to Varennes to help us ;-)

Comment: Hi Yves!  I added more info about how to access the magic - It's not _that_ automatic, I suppose :)  Nice to know you are upgraded - feel free to ping me if you get stuck with anything.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why the link gets me to my project homepage... But the Configure Features link is not there. Strange since I am an admin and the doc states that 
"If Configure Features doesn't appear, either your project has already been updated with all features available, or else you don’t have the required permissions to configure features."
I guess I will have to do it manually.

Comment: Yves - Did you upgrade to the Beta or the Release Candidate?

Comment: I updated from 2010 to RC directly. By the way, everything works great now! Thanks!