# VS 2012 with TFS 2012: "My Work"/Code Review feature not available in Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer, tfs-code-review

I already tried the new Team Project Templates and the Code Review Work Item Type is available but the feature does not show up in Team Explorer.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use Code review feature in TFS 2012 RC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040977/cannot-use-code-review-feature-in-tfs-2012-rc)

Comment: I understand the fact that it could have something to do with "outdated" process templates but I also get this behavior with new team projects. These new projects also use the new versions of the project templates.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using? It is only available in Premium and Ultimate edition.

Comment: Professional... Thanks man! Can you write an answer, then I'll mark it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by MikeR I was not using the correct edition of Visual Studio. The features is only available in Premium and Ultimate edition.

Comment: There most be another reason.  One of my devs has VS2012/2013 Ultimate and they don't have it.  I have it on mine.

Comment: Are you using TFS 2012 or above?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I am using VS 2013 **Premium** and code review is also not available. I have spent the last 20 minutes searching for a solution.